# Magento 2.1.7 to 2.1.8 upgrade issue

Tags: upgrade, magento-2.1.8

During Magento 2 upgrade process from 2.1.7 to Magento 2.1.8, when I run command: `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
I was getting below error:

> Cannot instantiate interface
>   Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigSourceInterface in
>   /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:73

Answer (score 3):

If you get above error, and you have redis configured in your Magento installation. Then this issue can be fixed by one of below solutions.

1. Just disable Redis and process your further Magento upgrade steps, it should work command
2. Just update the Credis module latest one, it can solved this issue in Magento 2.1.8.
   https://github.com/colinmollenhour/credis/archive/1.8.2.tar.gz

I hope this will resolve your issue. In my case 1st solution solved my problem.

Comment: FYI... It's "Redis" not "Radis". ... Redis was definitely the issue for me. The client dev server had a unique Redis setup that was difficult to clear, so I disabled it for now until we can determine a better way to do it.

Comment: Thanks @gtr1971 I have edited my answer and corrected spelling.

Answer (score 0):

In most of my cases to solve this problem:

If you got redis connect to redis cli

```
redis-cli -h 192.168.10.10
```

And next run `flushdb` or `flushall`

If no redis, remove cache from `var`

```
rm -rf var/generation var/di
```

After that back to PHP CLI and run again

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```